# Is there a way of preloading other components after the main component has loaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My app is set up so that each of my pages are different components, and I'm switching between them with react-router and a nav-bar which is outside the {this.props.children}. Now, when I click the second page, which is a gallery of images, it takes a while to load all the images, and the result is that I can see the browser rendering the component.

Is there a way to asynchronously preload my different components after the main component has loaded and rendered? I would also like to delay my initial render until all visible components have been loaded and ready for rendering. Is this possible with react?